# How can I make a column auto_increment while there is a FK on it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `products` which has a column named `id`. That column is primary but not auto_increment. When I want to make it auto_increment, it throws this error message:

> #1833 - Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'unique_products_ibfk_1' of table 'mydb.unique_products'

How can I force it to be converted to auto_increment? Noted that the date into `unique_products` table is worthy for me and I cannot remove them.

Comment: can you remove the fk create the auto_increment and then add the fk again?

Comment: Any way provide some sample data and create table ddl so we can reproduce the situation.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sounds good .. lemme try it out ..

Comment: after reading Toshio answer I relize not sure what is your scenario, that is why is better you provide the create table statement so the question is clear.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Ok, I removed that FK, made `id` column auto_increment, after that made that FK again. All Fine.

Comment: Ok then, im glad could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a FK as auto_increment. Image your id in product will autoincrement to id 100 but the foreing table it is linked to doesn't have id 100. It will cause a conflict and the data won't be inserted.

You have to remove the FK if you want the id to be auto_increment.

Answer (score 0):

Could not reproduce this on version 5.5.52.

Taking a look at the MySQL Bug Tracker, it says that this is affecting versions 5.6.24 and 5.6.27 (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77591)

I assume that you are on one of those versions. Workaround might be to disable the FK, execute an ALTER TABLE, and re-enable the FK constraint.